# Show a raw list of items after deletion another item with jq

Tags: json, jq

I've got a json file with the following content:

```
 {
    "stuff": {
        "usfull": [
            "aa",
            "bb",
            "cc",
            "dd"
        ],
        "usefulAsWell": [
            "ab",
            "cd",
            "ef",
            "gh"
        ],
        "waste": [
            "12",
            "34",
            "56"
        ],
        "moreWaste": [
            "78"
        ]
    }
 }
```

I would need a plain list of the items "useful" and "usefulAsWell". I don't know if more useful items will be added later on, but I know which items are waste and want them included instead of just listing the useful ones.

With the following command I already got a list, but it still contains format characters like [],"

```
cat example.json | jq -r '.stuff | del(.waste,.moreWaste) | .[]'

[
  "aa",
  "bb",
  "cc",
  "dd"
]
[
  "ab",
  "cd",
  "ef",
  "gh"
]
```

With the following command I get a nice list, but it unfortunately contains the waste:

```
cat example.json | jq -r '.stuff[] | .[]'

aa
bb
cc
dd
ab
cd
ef
gh
12
34
56
78
```

When trying to add the deletion part, I get an error message:

```
cat example.json | jq -r '.stuff[] | del(.waste,.moreWaste) | .[]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:24): Cannot index array with string "waste"
```

Any idea on this topic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the problem contains an inconsistency (a typo?), but it looks like you're after:

```
.stuff | del(.waste) | del(.moreWaste) | .[][]
```

which, as you implicitly note, can be abbreviated to:

```
.stuff | del(.waste, .moreWaste) | .[][]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This works fine. I still have no idea why, but I just need to get deeper into jq I guess. It feels strange from time to time.